# android - BitmaDescriptorFactory doesnt find source

Tags: android, eclipse, resources, bitmapfactory

i have been working with Google Maps V2 for a while now and one part of is is adding the markers.

```
googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(m.get(i).getTitle())
            .position(lat)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
```

and everything works just fine. Until the next day, when i try to run it i get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.bn(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(Unknown Source)
```

at first I tried to clean the project, build it, restart eclipse, restart computer but nothing helped. Later I searched the forums and added:

```
try {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but I still get the exact same error as before.
i must say again that in a circle of 16 hours I didn't edit the project or the BitmapDescriptorFactory at all.
what could have gone wrong, and how can i repair it ??

Comment: did you try to close the project, start eclipse with `eclipse --clean` and re-open the project?

Comment: how do i "eclipse --clean"?

Comment: command line. Even in windows, go to the folder containing your eclipse executable and run `eclipse --clean`.

Answer (score 3):

in the end BitmapDescriptorFactory is part of Google Play Services. And it turns out I had an outdated version of it. When I updated Google Play Services, everything worked fine :)